# Radio antenna as WiFi

Tags: rf, antenna

My school is a technical school that used to make ham radio communications (AM, I think). The thing is, we have a huge antenna that isn't being used. So, could we use it as a WiFi antenna?

Comment: good answers are already given, but would this not be an opportunity to consider a school project which involves Ham Radio? You might find yourself interested?  _just an idea_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost certainly not.

Every antenna has a range of frequencies it's designed to transmit and/or receive. A large antenna designed for amateur radio, like the one you're describing, would probably be tuned for frequencies in the kilohertz to low megahertz range. It would be completely ineffective for the 2.4 or 5.8 GHz signals used for WiFi.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed to know, I didn't know every antenna had a fixed frequency range.

Comment: In actuality given things like overtone resonance it's not necessarily easy to predict how the antenna itself would fare - it might actually work after a fashion, but would certainly not be a *good* choice.  However the *feedline* to the antenna is likely to have a huge amount of loss at the these frequencies, any matching networks or loading coils built into the antenna could pretty thoroughly kill the wifi signal - and besides, on the roof isn't necessarily where you want your antenna anyway.